# Minecraft gamerule keepinventory

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing minecraft 1.7.2 and I type `/gamerule keepinventory true`, and it says that there's no `keepinventory` rule. How do I keep inventory on death? I'm fighting the Ender Dragon and keep dying.

Answer (score 20):

The `/gamerule` command is case-sensitive. A quick check on the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Gamerule#Game_Rules) indicates that the correct casing would be `/gamerule keepInventory true`, with a capital 'I'.

Comment: THANK YOU!! I have been trying to figure it out. I dint even think about going on the Wiki.

Comment: @josh If this works for you, you should accept the answer.

Comment: @Josh Hint: After you've typed the first few characters of a command, hit the [TAB] key for auto-completion. If auto completion doesn't work, you've probably already typed the command wrong.

Comment: One thing that I ran into is that if you type `/gamerule keepInventory 1`, it will save, but will not work. Be sure to use `true` and `false` exactly!